# Converting the return value of a SELECT in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm fairly new to MySQL so I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this wrong, but I have a database column of type `DATETIME`. I populate this data using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO check_times (fullname, time) VALUES (%s, FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time=FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)
```

`fullname` is a unique string and I am either adding a new row or updating the time value if it already exists. The timestamp I have is a Unix timestamp but I store it in the database as a `DATETIME` so that I can see easily what date it is when viewing the data.

My issue is that in my application I need to compare the timestamp I have in the app (a Unix timestamp) against the value in the database. When I get the value in the database I receive a `datetime` object (in python) and I am unable to compare the two values. How would I go about getting mysql to convert the returned `datetime` value back into a Unix timestamp, allowing for easy conversion?

I thought it might be something like the following:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) FROM check_times WHERE fullname=%s
```

based from [this](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-unix_timestamp-function.php) page, but it didn't work. Using the following python code I get a return value of a tuple containing `(2018, )`

```
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) FROM check_times WHERE fullname=%s", (fullname,))
time = cursor.fetchone()
cursor.close()
```

If I run the above code but with the command `SELECT time FROM check_times WHERE fullname=%s` instead I get a tuple with a `datetime.datetime` object of the date stored in the database.

I'm not sure what terms I can google as everything I try doesn't return helpful information.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Tom, the coversion into timestamp at sql level should have worked. What error did yoi get, maybe it's a technicality... Alternatively check out the datetime module in python documentation. If you get a datetime object in results, it probably has a method that returns a timestamp

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've updated the main question to provide what return result I get.

Comment: Try extracting timestamp from the datetime object with `datetime.timestamp()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where I was going wrong. While developing the code to update a row I accidentally had made it so that it inserted the Unix timestamp of `2018`. The code from the question is functioning correctly and it was returning this value - I was being thrown off because I was expecting a much larger number to be returned. I found out after I cleared the table and ran through the insertion code again. The dangers of late-night programming I guess.